# IS NOT NULL - A simple google sheets query issue

Tags: google-sheets

I want my google sheets query to just filter out the rows with a blank value and possibly the ones containing specific words as well

Here's an example spreadsheet, I've tried using "where B is not null" in the query but it's not working! I'm tearing my hair out over this as i'm sure it's a simple solution.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xZH1MKeqLa8r1gRGL9wYHEWe02wQoNNpqqL_ca1fGf0/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

you may need to test for empty string instead of null, you can add AND to remove other values:

```
=QUERY(A2:B6,"select A, B where B<>'Pizza' and B<>''")
```

Answer (score 0):

This just worked for me

```
=QUERY(A2:B6,"select A, B where B!='' ",0)
```